# Lua HTTP download and save to file

Tags: sockets, http, download, lua, luasocket

I'm trying to download and then save the contents to a xml file. The code I got is:

```
local filePath = currentDir().."/file.xml"

local http  = require("socket.http")
local xFile = io.open(filePath, "w")
local save = ltn12.sink.file(xFile)

http.request{addr, sink = save }
print("Done!")
```

It runs but the file is still empty. Can I get some help here please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its a syntactical mistake. You mixed two styles of calling http.request. Use

```
http.request{url = addr, sink = save }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, sometimes working when tired can make you do mistakes like that.